# Update sql query with php

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I have a table name is main_info. The page has loaded the query will work and it will create a html table and will write row values into table. I wanna get next value of idseq column. Firstly I got id_seq=5. Later I wanna get next value of id_seq=6 with a button. I thought to update my query with ajax but I couldn't do.  I hope you know what I mean. Plz help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php 
    include '../config.php';
    $var=5;
    $query="SELECT city, city_x, page_title, page_url, price, 
    date, situation, img, source FROM main_info where id_seq=$var";  
    $result = pg_exec($link, $query);
    $numrows = pg_numrows($result);
    echo  '<table border="1">
        <tr> 
            <th>id_seq</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>page_url</th>
        </tr>  ';
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id_seq = $row['id_seq'];
    $city= $row['city']; 
    $page_url= $row['page_url']; 
echo "<td>$id_seq</td><td>$city</td><td>$page_url</td></tr>";       
    }
   pg_close($link);
   echo '</table>';
?> 
    <button'>next_item</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I understand you want to dynamicly update the displayed data after pressing the button, right? If so, you will have to use ajax (to get) and some sort of (php) API that serves the data. Other possibility is to 'reload' the page with new data. This is more old style, but easier to accomplish from what you have now.

Comment: Basicly you're searching for pagination, I guess, right?

Comment: Yes you are right i want to update dynamically after pressing the button. I want to use ajax.

Comment: Then you will have to read about an API, or REST API. This is **too broad** to give you an answer here. Search for 'ajax' & php, 'API', 'REST'. We're happy to help if you have a specific problem!

Comment: Basicly you call a php-script via ajax. That script returns needed data based on specific url and posted parameters.

Comment: For example the button is clicked i sent to ajax.php $var+1 value. I got $var+1 in ajax.php. later i change my query id_seq=$var+1 then i sent query to index.php? My idea is correct?

Comment: Also when i return new query in ajax.php how it will change old query? My problem is here

Comment: no, your Idea is not correct. You need a seperate php script (or a complete REST API) that serves data depending on what you request. Search for pagination, API, ajax, ...

Comment: Okey so thanks for idea